# How to boot into Ubuntu from Macbook 3.1

Tags: 14.04, macbook

I am trying to install Lubuntu 14.04.1 on a macbook 3.1 and have been unable to get it to boot from either a dvd or a USB stick.

It always boots from the HDD into OS X.

I have tried holding down the option key, and I have tried holding down the letter "c".

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the grubloader as [described here.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377181&p=13817037#post13817037)

Simply press „e“ as soon as the selection menu is displayed. Move with the cursor keys to the line to be modified. After modification continue with F10.

If it won‘t boot at all, you need to check if your MB is capable to boot into 64 bit. Usually, Core2duo are capable, while Coreduo are not.